# Critical Growth of Dimension for Dense Cover by Linear Subspaces

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, linear-algebra, gn.general-topology, banach-spaces, topological-vector-spaces

Let $X$ be a separable Banach space of dimensional $>2$.  When does there exist a sequence positive integers $\{N_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{n}}$ such that

- For any sequence of distinct finite-dimensional subspaces $\{L_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ of $X$ we have:
  $$
  N_n\leq  \dim(L_n) (\forall n \in \mathbb{N})\,\Rightarrow \,\overline{\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} L_n} =X.
  $$
  *By distict, I simply mean that $L_n\neq L_m$ if $n\neq m$ but we can have containement*.
- There exists a sequence of subspaces $\{\tilde{L}_n\}$ of $X$ for which $$
  Dim(\tilde{L}_n)<N_n \mbox{ and } \overline{\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \tilde{L}_n} \neq X.
  $$
  Let's call such $\{N_n\}$ *critical* for $X$.

---

**Finite-Dimensional Intuition:**

If $X$ is finite-dimensional with dimension at-least $2$, then WLOG assume $X=\mathbb{R}^D$ for some positive integer $D>2$.  Then $N_n=\min\{n,D\}$ works.  But if $\tilde{L}_n$ are rotations of $\mathbb{R}^{D-1}\subseteq \mathbb{R}^D$ by $\pi_n$ about the origin, then $\tilde{L}_n$ satisfy the second condition.  So $N_n=\min\{n,D\}$ is *critical* in the above sense.

**Note:**  We can always construct a dense linearly independent subset of $X$ by from a topological basis (since X is infinite-dimensional).  So we can find $L_n$ with $1$-dimension each.  However, here, I'm looking for a "critical" integer $N$ above which any collection of $\{L_n\}$ must satisfy $\overline{\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} L_n} =X$.

---

**Edit: **  I removed the requirement of each $L_n$ to be distinct so that I can give my (updated) intuition in the finite-dimensional setting.

Comment: Thanks. But your question should be more concrete anyway. Because you can just take a collection of 1-dimensional subspaces with dense union, in which case the second condition holds and the first does not. Also $N$ can be taken to be equal to 1 and then the first part is trivial.

Comment: @TarasBanakh Yes I just noticed the bad formulation.  I meant to ask if there is a "critical dimension" above which any collection of subspaces of that dimension must have dense union.

Comment: I think nothing like you wish cannot hold because of the existence of basic sequences in any infinite-dimensional Banach space. Using a basic sequence you can form many finite-dimensional subspaces with desirable properties.

Comment: @TarasBanakh Yes, instead if we ask if there is a sequence of dimensions of these subspaces must grow at then I think its possible.  I put down the example in the finite-dimensional case also.

Comment: How can the first condition be satisfied, if X is infinite dimensional? We can pick each $L_n$ within a fixed closed hyperplane, with any finite dimension $N_n$ we like.